# How can some services apply HTTP proxy by modifying DNS server?

Tags: dns, proxy, reverse-proxy

Some services, like [ProxyDNS](http://proxydns.co/), provided a way to access region-restricted websites like Hulu. I believe this kind of services are based on HTTP proxy, when we accessing hulu.com, the HTTP proxy is applied to proxy the data from my computer to hulu.com.

However, how can they done this by just modifying my local DNS to their server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Forward and Reverse Proxies

There are two classes of HTTP Proxies, forward and reverse.

Forward proxies are what you configure in your browser settings (typically done within universities and companies). And this is the class of proxies that users are more familiar with.

On the other hand, a reverse proxy is transparent the user (the user is unaware of its existence) and typically sits in 'front' of the actual webserver.

The following SO answers explain these in more detail than I'd ever venture to write.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220907/reverse-proxy

### Hence

With this background, what a service like ProxyDNS would be doing is simpler to understand. Since your DNS queries are being routed to a server controlled by them, they reply to dns lookups for services like hulu.com with an alternate ip. This alternate ip is now a reverse-proxy that they run and it is very likely that this reverse-proxy is hosted in the US. Now, hulu.com itself therefore sees requests coming from a US address.

### hulu.com

#### from ProxyDNS

```
$ nslookup hulu.com 74.207.242.213
Server:     74.207.242.213
Address:    74.207.242.213#53

Name:   hulu.com
Address: 50.116.28.138
Name:   hulu.com
Address: 23.92.31.241
```

#### from my provider's dns

```
$ nslookup hulu.com
Server:     172.17.70.47
Address:    172.17.70.47#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   hulu.com
Address: 23.63.99.145
Name:   hulu.com
Address: 23.63.99.184
```

### en.wikipedia.org

#### from ProxyDNS

```
$ nslookup en.wikipedia.org 74.207.242.213
Server:     74.207.242.213
Address:    74.207.242.213#53

Non-authoritative answer:
en.wikipedia.org    canonical name = wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org.
wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org  canonical name = text-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org.
Name:   text-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org
Address: 208.80.154.224
```

#### from my provider's dns

```
$ nslookup en.wikipedia.org
Server:     172.17.70.47
Address:    172.17.70.47#53

Non-authoritative answer:
en.wikipedia.org    canonical name = wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org.
wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org  canonical name = text-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org.
Name:   text-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org
Address: 208.80.154.224
```